# Object doesn't support property or method '__defineGetter__'

Tags: javascript

I am using arbor js . But when i run ie8,9 and 10 browser it show on error  Object doesn't support property or method `__defineGetter__` . how can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__defineGetter__` is an old, proprietary way of defining property "getter" functions. If the library you're using relies on it, you can't use it on JavaScript engines that don't support it.

The modern, standard way of defining getter functions for properties doesn't use that syntax. Perhaps there's a more up-to-date version of the library you could use.

There are two/three current standard ways, and another coming:

Using `get` and `set` functions on an [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5):

```
var obj = {
    get foo() {
        return /*...foo value...*/;
    },
    set foo(v) {
      // Set foo value
    }
};
```

...or using [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {
    get: function() {
        return /*...foo value...*/;
    },
    set: function(v) {
      // Set foo value
    }
};
```

...or using [`Object.defineProperties`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.7) (or the second argument to [`Object.create`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5), which accepts the same thing):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    foo: {
        get: function() {
            return /*...foo value...*/;
        },
        set: function(v) {
            // Set foo value
        }
    }
});
```

For objects created via constructors, ES6 will also add [`class`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions):

```
class ThingWithFoo {
    get foo() {
        return /*...foo value...*/;
    }

    set foo(v) {
      // Set foo value
    }
}
```

Comment: fwiw, `Object.defineProperty` is the standard way to do this. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty.